# Ci-Merchant - Autorizing and later capturing a payment with PayPal Express

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, ci-merchant

I'm currently building an off-site payment solution for a website. I'm using CI-Merchant (I tried to use Omnipay but using Composer doesn't work for me).

I'm currently doing this (in a method of my controller). Also note that I'm using a tweaked version of CI-Merchant to allow sending to PayPal the cart of the customer. I just did these changes : https://github.com/guillermofr/ci-merchant/commit/70ea1a2864971078b3b67e5ca1051be174f23fa0

In my controller file :

```
//The library and the settings are initialized before
$this->merchant->initialize($this->APISettings);

$order = array(
           array(
              'name' => 'Voyage 1',
              'desc' => 'Relais du Plessis',
              'amt' => 50.00,
              'qty' => 1
           ),
           array(
              'name' => 'Voyage 2',
              'desc' => 'Domaine St-Hilaire',
              'amt' => 50.00,
              'qty' => 1
           )
);

$this->session->set_userdata('order',$order);

$params = array(
            'amount' => 100.00,
            'currency' => 'EUR',
            'items' => $order,
            'return_url' => base_url().'api/reservation/validation_commande',
            'cancel_url' => base_url().'api/reservation/annulation_commande'
);

$this->merchant->authorize($params);
```

Later, in another method of my controller (the one called when the payment is complete, the return_url) :

```
$this->merchant->initialize($this->APISettings);

$params = array(
        'amount' => 100.00,
        'currency' => 'EUR',
        'items' =>  $this->session->userdata('order'),
        'return_url' => base_url().'api/reservation/validation_commande',
        'cancel_url' => base_url().'api/reservation/annulation_commande'
);

$response = $this->merchant->authorize_return($params);
var_dump($response);

$gateway_reference = $response->reference();
```

What I want is just keep a footprint of the card, so that's why I'm getting the reference.

Question is, if I want to capture the payment later, how can I do ? I know that the method to call is $this->merchant->capture(); but I don't know what to pass in parameter.

Thanks in advance,

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, nevermind. I succeeded in installing Omnipay (which is a very good library), and to do this I simply get the $params array, and I'm pushing into him the transactionReference, via

```
$response->getTransactionReference();
```

Then you just need to call :

```
$response = $gateway->capture($params)->send();
```

and the reponse is okay !

Comment: Yip that is correct. CI-merchant works pretty much the same way, you get $response->reference() and pass that through to $gateway->capture(). But it's a much better idea to use Omnipay, CI-merchant is no longer supported.

Comment: Thanks for these awesome libraries Adrian, and thanks for the approval.